# I get Activation of Connection Failed - after restarting

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, amd-ryzen

I found dozens of these questions but they either didn't work or were way too specific for the user.

I have Lenovo Thinkpad E15 and freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04. First, it didn't find any wireless adapter but after researching a bit I installed the rtw89 driver and it worked, well halfway at least.

My home network connects but after rebooting it doesn't and gives "Activation of Connection failed.". I can connect to my mobile hotspot, but as I said not to my home network. After reboot and getting this error, when some time passes it connects again and I'm happy until my next reboot...

People at same questions seem to ask a command's output so I will add it too.
`sudo lshw -C network`'s output:

```
  *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 10
   serial: 38:f3:ab:b7:14:c1
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 
   mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-59-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.1.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:48 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:fd504000-fd504fff memory:fd500000-fd503fff
   *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 00
   serial: 74:4c:a1:d2:13:f1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw89_pci driverversion=5.8.0-59-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:69 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:fd400000-fd4fffff
```

`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`'s output:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8852]
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4852]
Kernel driver in use: rtw89_pci
Kernel modules: rtw89pci, wl
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @waltinator That made me see what's going on behind the walls! Thanks. Well, now I have new stuff to research...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution but I can use my WiFi, problem free after freshly installing Ubuntu 20.04 MATE. It uses 5.4 kernel opposite to Ubuntu 20.04's 5.8. I'm not sure if it was a kernel issue but it's gone with MATE.